# Making ^ work as MatrixPower for matrices

Tags: custom-notation

I'd like my expressions like `A^d` get interpreted as `MatrixPower[A, d]` for matrix arguments A, any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: `Power`  (`^`) is a built-in symbol. My suggestion: Don't mess with built-in symbols. You will be happier in the long run if you don't.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware this may break some things

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it is to use Notation package.

```
Needs["Notation`"]

distinguishMatrixPowerAndPower[A_, d_] := 
 If[SquareMatrixQ[A], MatrixPower[A, d], Power[A, d]]

Notation[A_^d_\[DoubleLongRightArrow]distinguishMatrixPowerAndPower[A_,d_]] (* this line is inserted using Notation Palette. *)
```

This is the result:

```
In[]:= {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}^2

Out[]= {{2, 3}, {3, 5}}

In[]:= 5^2

Out[]= 25
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm, my formulas are [extra beautiful](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/isserlis-inversion.nb) now!