# Make the ```*``` operation the Kronecker product by default for Kets?

Tags: tensors, quantum-computing

So given two "[Ket](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ket.html)" objects,

```
u = Ket[{-1/2}];
d = Ket[{1/2}];
```

Is there a way to define multiplication, `*`, so that by default when you run

```
u * d
```

the output is

```
Ket[{-1/2,1/2}]
```

?

Equivalently, given two vectors

```
u = {1,0};
d = {0,1};
```

Is there a way to make it so that `u * d` outputs `KroneckerProduct[u,d]` by default? I feel like surely somebody must have asked this question before, so apologies if this is a duplicate (I could not find the answer by searching).

The reason I want to do this is that I want Slater determinants that involve spin up/down states to automatically form the tensor product. That is, I'm trying to compute something like

```
Det[{
  {f[x1]*u, f[x1]*d},
  {f[x2]*u, f[x2]*d}
  }]
```

with an output of `f[x1] f[x2] (u*d - d*u)` (where of course this is non-zero because the tensor product doesn't commute).

Comment: You can define a multiplication on `Ket`s by using [`UpSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSet.html) or [`UpSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html)

Comment: Personally I would do something like `CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct` and use `:c*:` to input it. Technically you can modify definition of `Times`, but you may run into some unexpected behavior

Comment: For Ket objects, you can assign upvalues to easily do this. But I believe that the answer to your second question is, no, that is not possible directly. 'a*b' will always be parsed at first as 'Times[a,b]'. Vectors like '{1,0}' are Lists, and since the symbol List is locked, you can't assign any upvalues. Changing the definition of Times is possible but is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies! I've spent the last little while trying to learn what UpSet/TagSet/etc do. I'm amazed I've never heard of these capabilities. I'm not sure how to define a multiplication that doesn't commute though? I've tried ```Ket[{u}]*Ket[{d}] ^= Ket[{u, d}]```, but the problem is that both ```Ket[{u}]*Ket[{d}]``` and ```Ket[{d}]*Ket[{u}]``` return ```Ket[{u, d}]```. I must be misunderstanding something fundamental here...

Comment: @AlkaKadri in Mathematica 14, the following gives a nice summary of what's happening `ResourceFunction["TraceGraph"][ Ket[{u}]*Ket[{d}]]` . You can see that Mathematica sorts the arguments to `Times` before applying UpValues. Built-ins like Times/Plus assume commutativity/associativity

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I see! Is it the case then that it will never be possible to overload the Times operator so that it is non-commutative only for ```Ket```?

Comment: @AlkaKadri it might be possible, but it will require gaining some deep Mathematica knowledge that you'll soon forget :) Modifying built-ins is outside of the common path. I once tried hard to make my matrix powers look nice like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206684/217). It works 95% of the time, but the remaining 5% cause too much pain to rely on this

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Fair enough! I like the linked example you gave, but I guess if I want to accomplish what I want I should probably take the pains of defining a new determinant function that takes tensor products rather than multiplications...

Answer (score 0):

It is dangerous to change built in operators. It is better to define a new operator. However, if you know what you are doing, you can go ahead.

"Times" is protected. Therefore, you must unprotect it to make new definitions. After this, you can define the multiplication of kets and protect "Times" again.

```
Unprotect[Times];
Ket[x : {__}]* Ket[y : {__}] = Ket[Join[x, y]]
Protect[Times];
```

Now you can e.g. write:

```
Ket[{a}]* Ket[{b}]
```

[image: Ket[{a, b}]]

Or

```
Ket[{a1, a2}]* Ket[{b1, b2}]
```

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Unfortunately, ```Ket[{u}]*Ket[{v}]``` and ```Ket[{v}]*Ket[{u}]``` still return the same output with this method :((

Comment: `Ket[{u}]*Ket[{v}]` returns `Ket[{u, v}]` for me.  If not, there might be a version problem. I have version 14.0

Comment: @AlkaKadri @DanielHuber to be clear the problem is that `Ket[{v}]*Ket[{u}]` would also return `Ket[{u, v}]`. Likely OP is better off just defining some replacement behavior for a `NonCommutativeMultiply` to avoid the `Orderless` attribute of `Times`.

Comment: @AlkaKadri  To rearrange its argument is a feature of "Times". If you want to eliminate this, you need to define your own time operator.